# PHP - Always get Error in Form

Tags: php, forms

I have this form but I keep getting the `"You cannot use less than 7 characters in your shout."` error. This is what I have, and to me it seems fine:

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $shout = strip_tags($_POST['shout']);
            $value = (!empty($shout)) ? 'value="' . $shout . '"' : '';

            if(empty($shout)) {
                $response[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error!</strong> Your shout cannot be empty.</div>';
            } elseif($shout > 50) {
                $response[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error!</strong> You cannot use more than 50 characters in your shout.</div>';
            } elseif($shout < 7) {
                $response[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error!</strong> You cannot use less than 7 characters in your shout.</div>';
            } else {
                $response[] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Your shout has been posted and placed in the shoutbar.</div>';
            }
        }

        if(isset($response)) {
            foreach($response as $respons) {
                echo $respons;
            }
        }
    ?>
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Your shout</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="shout" placeholder="Type your shout" <?php echo $value; ?> class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Post it" name="submit" class="btn btn-default"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Why do I keep getting this error? The input I typed is inbetween 7 and 50 characters so it should go and take the `else` path.

Comment: well, shout is a string. what do you want to compare to? the length of the string? Then you should get the [length of the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

Comment: `(int)"i am a long shout" ===  0` and `0 < 7` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `strlen($shout)` in your comparison. You're comparing the `$shout` as a string and the integer `7` is also being converted to a string for the comparison, but you're intending to compare the integer length to another integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare lenghts, using mb_strlen() (multibyte) instead strlen(), available since PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, to avoid fatal errors on string lenghts ending in a non standard char, like latin tilde (á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ) or any other special char.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strlen.php